# Forwarding email message breaks DKIM

Tags: postfix, exchange, dkim, opendkim, mail-forwarding

I have problem with postfix, DKIM and forwarding messages. In almost every article about DKIM I’m reading that “if I do not modify any fields in message header, DKIM signature should still be valid after forwarding”. Unfortunately it is not in my case.

My configuration consist of an MS Exchange server, hidden behind firewall, and an intermediate linux box with postfix and opendkim (and also opendmarc), sitting between Exchange server and Internet.

When external user (say a@sourcedomain.com) send a message to an internal user (say user@mydomain.com), it first reaches my postfix linux box, where DKIM signature is verified, and then is successfully forwarded to internal Exchange server. An replay, send from Exchange server, goes though the same linux/postfix box, which this time adds DKIM signature to it. So, all is working fine with messages originating from mydomain.com or destinated to it.
But when user enables on his Exchange account (user@mydomain.com)  forwarding all incoming messages to an external mailbox (say b@destination.domain.com) then linux/postfix box sees a@source.domain.com in a From: field and tries to verify DKIM signature, which obviously fails. Here is sample log for such case:

```
2024-01-08T13:00:42.599247+01:00 myserver postfix/smtpd[11432]: 9242D1E00DE: client=unknown[10.0.0.1]
2024-01-08T13:00:42.601628+01:00 myserver postfix/cleanup[11423]: 9242D1E00DE: warning: header Subject: =?utf-8?B?VcW8eXRrb3duaWsgU3p5bWHFhHNrYSBvcHVibGlrb3dhxYIgd2lhZG9tb8Wb?=? =?utf-8?B?xIc=?= from unknown[10.0.0.1]; from=<user@mydomain.com> to=<b@destination.domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<smtp.mydomain.com>
2024-01-08T13:00:42.601745+01:00 myserver postfix/cleanup[11423]: 9242D1E00DE: message-id=<243e3be85441415a829c5e6ac0b54ada@smtp.mydomain.com>
2024-01-08T13:00:42.606954+01:00 myserver opendkim[975]: 9242D1E00DE: no signing domain match for 'source.domain.com'
2024-01-08T13:00:42.607061+01:00 myserver opendkim[975]: 9242D1E00DE: no signing subdomain match for 'source.domain.com'
2024-01-08T13:00:42.609717+01:00 myserver opendkim[975]: 9242D1E00DE: s=selector2 d=source.domain.com a=rsa-sha256 SSL error:02000068:rsa routines::bad signature
2024-01-08T13:00:42.609953+01:00 myserver opendkim[975]: 9242D1E00DE: bad signature data
2024-01-08T13:00:42.610192+01:00 myserver postfix/cleanup[11423]: 9242D1E00DE: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from unknown[10.0.0.1]: 5.7.0 bad DKIM signature data; from=<user@mydomain.com> to=<b@destination.domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<smtp.mydomain.com>
```

How could I solve this? (IP of my internal Exchange server is of course listed in InternalHost). Should I try to sign such messages with mydomain.com key (rather not) or just allow to pass it unmodified though my linux/postfix box? The second option seems right one, but I don’t know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Backup configuration files
cp /etc/postfix/main.cf /etc/postfix/main.cf.bak
cp /etc/opendkim.conf /etc/opendkim.conf.bak

# Modify Postfix configuration to always add missing headers
echo "always_add_missing_headers = yes" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf

# Restart Postfix
systemctl restart postfix

# Review and update DKIM configuration (replace 'source.domain.com' with your actual domain)
sed -i 's/^Domain.*$/Domain source.domain.com/' /etc/opendkim.conf

# Restart OpenDKIM
systemctl restart opendkim

# Test DKIM signing on a forwarded message (replace 'forwarded_message.eml' with your actual file)
opendkim-testmsg < forwarded_message.eml

# Monitor logs for any errors
journalctl -u postfix -u opendkim -e

echo "Script execution completed."
```

This script includes steps to backup configuration files, modify Postfix settings, update OpenDKIM configuration, restart services, and perform a DKIM test on a forwarded message. Replace placeholder values (e.g., 'source.domain.com', 'forwarded_message.eml') with your actual domain and file.Review your OpenDKIM configuration (e.g., /etc/opendkim.conf) and ensure that the signing domain (d=) is set correctly. It seems that the signing domain is not matching during verification.

Answer (score 0):

You may could try configure postfix to act as a relay host. This will allow emails to be forwarded without being modified by postfix.
To do this, you could add the following lines to your postfix configuration file:
`relayhost = [internal.exchange.server.ip.address]`
`smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic`
Replace [internal.exchange.server.ip.address] with the IP address of your internal Exchange server.
Then, create a file called generic in the /etc/postfix directory and add the following line:
`@source.domain.com user@mydomain.com`
This will tell postfix to replace the From: address in emails from the source.domain.com domain with user@mydomain.com, which will allow the emails to pass through without being modified by postfix and without causing the DKIM signature to fail verification.
It is recommended that you test it to see if this works for you.

Comment: Sorry for lack of answer. Your propositions (both from you and from @Turdie) assumes that I know in adwance @source.comain.com but this not true! Mails could arrive just from any domain, and are forwarded to external email box (f.e. due to user being on vacation).